# segfault when using strtok_r

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

i want to split a string in c with this code:

```
char *search = "+" ;
char *temp1;
char *temp2;
char *saveptr1, *saveptr2 ;
int operand1 ;
int operand2 ;
int result ;
char sumBuff [5][25]    
temp1 = strtok_r(sumBuff[sumCounter-1], search, &saveptr1) ;
operand2 = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, search, &saveptr1));
temp2 = strtok_r(temp1, ".", &saveptr2) ;
operand1 = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, ".", &saveptr2)) ;
```

but when i run this in my main code i get the segmentation fault.
and this is the trace stack result:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7834517 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7830f60 in atoi () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x000000000040108c in plusExec (arg=0x0) at cm.c:112
#3  0x00007ffff7bc4182 in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff78f147d in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

`cm.112` is `operand2 = atoi(...)`
How can i correct this error?

Comment: Well, did you step through the code and examine the variables in the debugger?  This is not a complete program, and you are showing referenced to variables that are not defined ( sumCounter, etc).

Comment: The crash is in `atoi()`, which doesn't like getting `NULL`. You need to check whether `strtok_r()` returned `NULL`.

Comment: @EOF can you help me more?what should i do exactly?

Comment: Well, you could store the result of the `strtok_r()` into a `char *tokresult`, then check `if (!tokresult){/*handle the error*/}`.

Comment: BTW: `sumBuff[sumCounter-1]` I've never used a negative index ever. And: what is `sumCounter` , anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not check for the return of `strtok_r`, which can be NULL and therefore crash `atoi`.

And in this case:

```
temp2 = strtok_r(temp1, ".", &saveptr2) ;
operand1 = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, ".", &saveptr2)) ;
```

...you seem to be looking for **two consecutive points**? Such as 5.123.723? If there is only one, `atoi` will receive NULL and coredump.

If there shouldn't be two consecutive "."'s, then that's likely to be a bug.

Supposing it is *not*, try:

```
temp2 = strtok_r(temp1, ".", &saveptr2); // E.g. 5

// If there is no other token, operand1 is set to zero.
operand1 = 0;
if (temp2 != NULL) {
    char *temp3;
    temp3 = strtok_r(NULL, ".", &saveptr2); // E.g. 123, or NULL
    if (temp3 != NULL) {
        operand1 = atoi(temp3);
    }
}
```

(Same approach for the first `atoi`).

Depending on the data format, you might perhaps employ a *parser function* that would return an array of integers and its cardinality; again, **if you need to deal with variably-dotted quantities**, such as 192.168.1.1 or 1.2.7.0.80.17 - otherwise you needn't bother:

```
/**
 * Parses a string in the format 1.2343.293.777
 * @param char * inputString       Input string
 * @param int * vect               Vector where to store integers
 * @param size_t n                 Maximum vector size
 * @return size_t                  Number of integers returned
 */

size_t parseDottedIntegers(char *inputString, int *vect, size_t n) {
    size_t i = 0;
    char *p;
    char *save = NULL;
    p = strtok_r(inputString, ".", &save);
    while (i < n) {
        vect[i++] = atoi(p);
        p = strtok_r(NULL, ".", &save);
        if (NULL == p) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    // Error (e.g. too many parts)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tend to be wary of default values of zero for signed types.

Comment: @lserni in `sumBuff[sumCounter-1]` there is a string like `123.456+789` which `123` is the line number and `456` and `789` are my operand1 and 2

Comment: the code already got by the 123. in the first call to strtok_r().  so the following calls to strtok_r() should be: 'temp3 = strtok_r(NULL, "+", &saveptr2);'

Comment: Yes. But in the original code, it seemed to me there were two consecutive "."'s, so I thought we were perhaps dealing with dotted quads or suchlike. @EmadSmart, perhaps you ought to add some comments such as `/* Here we look for the 456 part */` in your original code. That would help focus on what's going on, what's expected, and one could even `printf()` the results to see whether they match.

Comment: @user3629249 is this correct? [SplitStringWithStrtok_r](http://pastebin.com/0NwAv4si)

Comment: @lserni Excuse me you're right i will do this next times.